# Вы можете принять ответ через 0 секунд

Tags: дефект, нытьё

Скриншот сделать не успел, но что-то не так в этом времени))

> Вы можете принять ответ через 0 секунд

Comment: Нет скриншота - нет проблемы.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56998/